# Why matchPhrasePrefix query does not work with underscored text fields?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In my elastic index, I've a document with a text field with underscore separated word like 'test_upload_document.txt'. I need to perform a full text search on this index and I am using a `MatchPhrasePrefixQuery` in the following way

```
BoolQueryBuilder qb = new BoolQueryBuilder();
qb.must(QueryBuilders.matchPhrasePrefixQuery("_all", queryParameters.getFirst("keyword")));
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch(index)
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
                .setQuery(qb)
                .setSize(100).get();
do {
    for (SearchHit hit : searchResponse.getHits().getHits()) {
        LOGGER.debug("source: "+hit.getSourceAsString());
        //some more operations goes here
    }
    searchResponse = client.prepareSearchScroll(searchResponse.getScrollId()).setScroll(new TimeValue(60000)).execute().actionGet();
} while(searchResponse.getHits().getHits().length != 0);
```

And my document contains multiple text fields

```
{
    'name':'test_upload_document.txt'
    'user': 'user name'
}
```

My problem is when I run the above query with the keyword `test` it returns the document correctly. It even works with `test_`. But if I used `upload` or other parts of the name field it does not work.

Is this how the MatchPhrasePrefix works? If yes what is the query I can use to achieve this? I tried using QueryString, MatchPhrase, and Match. But all fail to return the doc correctly.

Comment: Ideally MatchPhrasePrefix and Match Phrase should work if you are querying for exact text. you can check the mapping of field in your index and check which analyzer is used for the field.                                               If you want to get result with individual word then you can use stop analyzer with match clause or create your own analyzer.